# Why does the C++ standard library always pass std::initializer_list<T> by value rather than by reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference, standards, pass-by-value

As a C++ programmer, I have been taught the simple rule of passing parameters:

> Passing parameter `T` by value when `sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*)` or for *constructing in-place and move in*.

However, the C++ standard library seems not comply with the rule. For [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), `sizeof(std::initializer_list<T>)` is greater than `sizeof(void*)`, but `std::vector` has a constructor:

```
vector(std::initializer_list<T>, const Allocator&);
```

**Why does the C++ standard library always pass** `std::initializer_list<T>` **by value rather than by reference?**

Comment: `initializer_list` is not a container, and was designed to be passed by value. Many people now regard it as a mistake

Comment: @M.M Interesting. Can you  point us to a discussion?

Comment: `initializer_list` was always designed as a "lightweight wrapper" (if I remember the words correctly) for an array, rather than a container.  That normally implies the overhead of copying - including passing by value - is acceptably low.  That would explain why the standard library passes them by value rather than reference.   As to that being considered a mistake - I'd be interested in the discussion of that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Your question seems to be "I have this rule, and the C++ standard library doesn't follow this rule. Why not?" Does the standard library need to have a justification for not following a rule of yours? Also, there are many other places where the standard library doesn't follow your rule (for example, every algorithm that takes a predicate or other callable does so by value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From cppreference on [initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

> The lifetime of the underlying array is the same as any other temporary object, except that initializing an initializer_list object from the array extends the lifetime of the array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary (with the same exceptions, such as for initializing a non-static class member).

So `initializer_list` already acts like a reference to a temporary.

The idea behind `initializer_list` is to move the data from temporaries or copy it from read-only memory directly to the destination container. It is not a container per se.

Answer (score 2):

Since in the scope of initialization it is known that value will be used (ie copied) as  properties of the container (eg vector, map,...) there is no performance gain in passing them by reference.